# Sharepoint Designer Set Task Field drop-down is showing empty

Tags: workflow, column

Using SPD 2010 I created an Approval process. I have added few custom field to my task list and now under "Before Task is assigned", the action "Set Task field" is not showing anything on the dropdown-menu that used to have the list of fields in the task.

I removed the fields added, and I also restore from a previous backup, but the list of fields is not been displayed. I have used this action already on the site, and the rules that I set before the problem arisen are working perfectly.

Lastly, after days searching seems like in the entire Internet nobody had have this problem before :( Any help will be greatly appreciated.